# Numpy indexing oddity: How to subselect from multidimensional array and keep all axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multi-dimensional array, and have two lists of integers, L_i and L_j, corresponding to the elements of axis-i and axis-j I want to keep. I also want to satisfy the following:

1. Keep original dimensionality of the array, even if L_i or L_j
   consists of just 1 element (in other words I dont want a singleton
   axis to be collapsed)
2. Preserve the order of the axes

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Here is a reproducible example that shows some of the unexpected behavior I've been getting:

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(120).reshape(5,4,3,2)
aa.shape
### (5,4,3,2) as expected

aa[:,:,:,[0,1]].shape
### (5, 4, 3, 2) as expected

aa[:,:,:,[0]].shape
### (5,4,3,1) as desired. Notice that even though the [0] is one element, 
### that last axis is preserved, which is what I want

aa[:,[1,3],:,[0]].shape
### (2, 5, 3) NOT WHAT I EXPECTED!!
### I was expecting (5, 2, 3, 1)
```

Curious as to why numpy is collapsing and reordering axes, and also best way to do my subsetting correctly.

Comment: Try `aa[:, :1, :, :1]`

Comment: While this works for the toy example I gave, what if L_i = [0, 3, 4] or some other non-consecutive range?

Comment: What if, indeed. Make an actual MCVE

Comment: I do believe my example is MVCE. It demonstrates the oddities of using lists to select indices for various axes, even though my particular choice does have a hard-coded workaround.
With that said, I will tweak my example so that it cannot be solved using ":1" notation

Comment: `aa[:,[[1],[3]],:,[0]].shape` produces a `(2,1,5,3)`.  The (2,1) shape `broadcasts` with (1,) to give the (2,1) dimension.  In your example a (2,) `broadcasts` with (1,) to select just (2,).  The (5,3) dimensions are from the slices, and as explained in the comment, are place last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the answers to your questions...

- Why is numpy collapsing the axes?

Because advanced indices `[1,3]` and `[0]` are broadcast together to form a shape `(2,)` subspace which replaces the subspace they index (i.e. the axes with size `4` and `2` respectively).

- Why is numpy reordering the axes?

Because the advanced indices are separated by a slice, there is no unambiguous place to drop the new shape `(2,)` subspace. As a result, numpy places it at the front of the array, with the sliced dimensions trailing afterward (shape `(5, 3)`).

... and thus you are left with a shape `(2, 5, 3)` array.

For more info, see the section in the numpy guide on [combining basic and advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).

---

PS: It is still possible to get your desired shape using just a single indexing call, but you'll have to part ways with the slices and instead define indices that broadcast to shape `(5, 2, 3, 1)`, for instance using [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> aa[ np.ix_([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0]) ].shape
(5, 2, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the axes one at a time:

```
aa[:, [1, 3], :, :][..., [0]].shape
(5, 2, 3, 1)
```